# Question about datafactories alerts in azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I would like to know the best way of alerting logs when a pipeline fails in Azure Datafactory without having to configure each Datafactory.

I'm trying to do it in the following way:

I have 40 Datafactories that I've set up to send the diagnostic to a workspace log. After that, I made an alert that utilizes a consult with a "Status==Failed" conditional. If it returns, it will be alerted. However, is there any chance of it not working since the consult only has 1 conditional? For example, is it possible that it won't alert or that it duplicates? If 30 different Datafactories pipelines fail will I be alerted of all the 30 fails?

Answer (score 0):

You would be getting multiple alerts for each data factory based on the log query output. If you want to have a customized consolidated alert for multiple data factories then you need to explore using custom solution using azure functions or logic apps.